# Dibujar cuadrado con distintos caracteres

Tags: java

Estoy empezando con programación y estoy realizando una actividad que me es complicada, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar!

La actividad consiste en hacer un rectángulo. Para ello, se le pide al usuario el nº de columnas, nº de filas y si quiere que el rectángulo sea relleno o vacío (Para vacío debe pulsar nº 0).

Además, el rectángulo debe cumplir las siguientes características:

- para cada una de las cuatro esquinas, se utilizará el carácter '+';
- para los bordes superior e inferior, el carácter '-';
- para los bordes izquierdo y derecho, el carácter '|';
- para el interior:

  - si va sin rellenar (vacía), el carácter espacio (' ');
  - si va rellena, caracteres numéricos que indiquen el número de fila (sin tener en cuenta
    el borde superior). Es decir, caracteres '1' para toda la primera fila de relleno,
    caracteres '2' para la segunda fila de relleno, y así sucesivamente.

En primer lugar, os muestro el código que he escrito:

```java
        //Línea superior e inferior
        for (int f=0; f<=fila; f++) {
           System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();        
        
        //Centro de la forma
        for (int c=0; c<=columna-2;c++){
         System.out.println("|");
        }
        if (relleno==0){
           for(int h=1;h<columnas-2; h++){
           System.out.println(" ");
           }
        }else 
           for (int r=1; r<columnas-2; r++){
             for(int f=c; f<=c; f++){
             System.out.println(columna);
             }
           System.out.println("\n");
           }
        }
```

Tras introducir el código que he pensado. No sabría como terminar la parte de la línea superior e inferior porque también tengo que indicar que esas líneas van con el carácter "-" pero las esquinas van con el carácter "*", y esto no se cómo sería posible hacerlo.

Por otro lado, en el centro de la forma, he indicado que la líneas verticales se escriben con el carácter "|". Y dependiendo si no tiene relleno estará con huecos en blancos y, en cambio, si está relleno se hará con números en orden.

Comment: las esquinas por fin se llenan con el caracter ¨*¨ o ¨+¨, mejor pon una imagen que describa el resultado final

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta requiere de lógica al contrario de ayuda técnica en el tienes que leer para aprender nuevos temas, las preguntas de lógica vas a tener que sentarte tomar lápiz y papel para plantear la solución, puede haber varias formas de solucionarlo pero las ideas son similares.
Te planteo una solución.

```
        int fila,columna,relleno;
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Numero de filas:");
        fila=leer.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Numero de columnas:");
        columna=leer.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Vacio -->0 / Relleno -->1 :");
        relleno=leer.nextInt();        
        System.out.println("\t DIBUJANDO EL CUADRILATERO \n");
        for (int f=0; f<fila; f++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columna; c++) {
                //logica para la primera y ultima fila
                if(f==0||f==(fila-1)){
                    //las esquinas se dibujan con +
                    if(c==0||c==(columna-1)){
                        System.out.print("+");
                    }
                    //la primera y ultima fila quitando los extremos van con -
                    else{
                        System.out.print("-");
                    }
                }
                //logica para las filas que no sean la primera ni la ultima
                else{
                    //la primera y ultima columna van con |
                    if(c==0||c==(columna-1)){
                        System.out.print("|");
                    }
                    //logica las columnas internos
                    else
                        //sin relleno
                        if(relleno==0){
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        //con relleno, digitamos el numero de fila
                        else{
                            System.out.print(f);
                        }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Observación**
Si ingresas que el número de filas es mayor que 11 el dibujo saldrá deformado, la solución es simple pero lo dejo para que lo hagas